# Probability of connected graph on torus

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, graph-theory

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a graph on n vertices constructed in the following way:

Each vertex $v \in V$ is positioned uniform randomly in $[0, 1] × [0, 1]$.

Connect two vertices $u, v \in V$ if $d(v,u) ≤ r$ where $d$ is the Euclidean distance on a Torus.

I would like to prove that for $r = 3\cdot\sqrt{\frac{2log(n)}{n}}$ the graph is connected with probability at least $1-\frac{1}{log(n)}$

I'm not even sure how to formulate the probability $Pr[\text{graph is connected}]$. If I knew this I would probably be able to apply a union bound and go with an Azuma/Janson or similar bound.

Comment: What makes you think that for that specific value of $r$ that the graph is connected if you can't formalize what it means for the graph to be connected?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas It seems as though the OP is saying that it is unclear how to express the probability that the graph is connected, *not* that there is any confusion regarding the definition of connectivity.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Just like Vidit Nanda wrote, I know what it means for a graph to be connected. It's expressing the probability for this event that is my problem. Would you please consider taking back the down-vote? (if that was you).

Comment: Connectedness implies there is a spanning tree containing all vertices. Maybe you can use that?

Comment: So my concern is how you could come up with such precise quantities for the radius and probability without having a way of checking connectedness in mind.

Comment: Some very closely related questions are addressed in Balister, Bollobás and Sarkar: 
Percolation, connectivity, coverage and colouring of random geometric graphs, in the Handbook of large-scale random networks published by Springer.

Comment: Formalization: Let $T$ be the torus and let $X = T^n$. This construction is a function $G$ from $X$ to graphs on vertex set $\{ 1,2 \ldots, n \}$. For any given graph $\Gamma$ on $\{ 1,2 \ldots, n \}$, the condition that $G(x) \supseteq \Gamma$ is closed. Therefore, the condition that $G(x)$ is closed is a union of closed conditions, and hence closed. A closed set is measurable; the conjecture is about the measure of this set.

Answer (score 2):

I don't remember the exact details, but the analysis of such problems can be found in Random Geometric Graphs by M. Penrose.
http://www.bioinfo.org.cn/~wangchao/maa/Random_Geometric_Graphs.pdf

From what I remember, the key insight is that in the large n limit, connectivity occurs at the same threshold that isolated points disappear, which is straightforward to check for your problem using a union bound.  The only remaining issue is the convergence rate, i.e. is 1/log(n) correct, which might require some effort.